# How to fix Malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: </html> in Laravel 5.6 centos 8 php fpm

Tags: laravel, cgi, fpm, centos8

My laravel application running successfully in centos 7 but when i upgrade to centos 8 with fpm is giving the issue on this line

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

From the log i only got this line

```
[Tue Feb 23 11:00:24.469530 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4872:tid 140202286769920] (22)Invalid argument: [client 10.10.x.x:63952] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

[Tue Feb 23 11:00:24.824516 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4872:tid 140202269984512] [client 10.10.x.x:63954] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Tue Feb 23 11:00:24.824562 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4872:tid 140202269984512] [client 10.10.x.x:63954] AH01070: Error parsing script headers